# nullpointerexception while calling a constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, jframe, jlabel

thanks for having time reading this. my problem here is that when i call the other class it gives me so many error and i dont know how to fix it. im hope you can :) ty and have a good day :)

here is my code

```
public class Xavier1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener,Runnable
{
JButton a[] = new JButton [10];
JLabel pin,acc;
JTextField acc1;
JButton del,ok,crt;
int c=0,d=0,e=0;
JPasswordField pin1;
JFrame x;
String us,pw;
JButton res,back,next;
JLabel n,accn,bal,age,sex,dep,pins;
JFrame X,r;
JTextField n1,accn1,bal1,sex1,age1,dep1;
JPasswordField pins1;
JLabel Xn,Xacc,Xbal,Xage,Xsex;
String xn,xacc,xbal,xage,xsex;



public void run()
{

}

public Xavier1()
{
    x = new JFrame("ATM");
    x.setLayout(null);
    x.setBounds(400,100,550,500);
    x.setVisible(true);

    JPanel x3 = new JPanel();
    x.add(x3);
    x3.setVisible(true);
    x3.setBounds(150,420,250,100);
    crt = new JButton("Create Account");
    crt.addActionListener(this);
    x3.add(crt);

    JPanel x2 = new JPanel();
    x.add(x2);
    x2.setBounds(150,10,250,100);
    x2.setVisible(true);
    x2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
    pin = new JLabel("PIN");
    acc = new JLabel("ACCOUNT NUMBER");
    pin1 = new JPasswordField(20);
    acc1 = new JTextField(20);

    x2.add(acc);
    x2.add(acc1);
    x2.add(pin);
    x2.add(pin1);


    JPanel x1 = new JPanel();
    x.add(x1);
    x1.setBounds(150,200,250,200);
    x1.setVisible(true);
    x1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    for(int b=0;b<10;b++)
    {
        a[b] = new JButton();
        a[b].setText(Integer.toString(b));
        x1.add(a[b]);
        a[b].addActionListener(this);
    }
    ok = new JButton("OK");
    ok.addActionListener(this);
    del = new JButton("DEL");
    del.addActionListener(this);
    x1.add(ok);
    x1.add(del);




}
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Xavier1 xs = new Xavier1();
    Thread xd = new Thread(xs);
    xd.setDaemon(true);



}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent z)
{
    Object zz = z.getSource();

    if(e == 0)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<a.length;c++)
        {
            if(zz == a[c])
            {
            acc1.setText(acc1.getText()+a[c].getText());
            }

        }
    }
    if(zz == ok)
    {
        e++;
    }
    if(e==2)
    {
        GateKeeper();


    }
    if(e == 1)
    {
        for(int d=0;d<a.length;d++)
        {
            if(zz == a[d])
            {
            pin1.setText(pin1.getText()+a[d].getText());
            }

        }

    }
    if(zz == crt)
    {
        Reg rs = new Reg();
        Thread sr = new Thread(rs);
        sr.start();
        x.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(zz == del)
    {
        if(e == 0)
        {
            acc1.setText(null);
        }
        if(e == 1)
        {
            pin1.setText(null);
        }
    }

}
public void GateKeeper()
{
    try
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("DATABASE.txt"));
        int loop = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int gk=0;gk<loop;gk++)
        {
            String ps[] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            us = ps[0];
            pw = ps[1];
            if(acc1.getText().equals(us));
            {
                if(pin1.getText().equals(pw))
                {
                    xn = ps[2];
                    xage = ps[3];
                    xsex = ps[4];
                    xbal = ps[5];
                    xacc = ps[0];



                            Xn = new JLabel("NAME: "+xn);
                            Xacc = new JLabel("ACCOUNT NUMBER: "+xacc);
                            Xage = new JLabel("AGE: "+xage);
                            Xsex = new JLabel("SEX: "+xsex);
                            Xbal = new JLabel("BALANCE: "+xbal);

                        Bank b = new Bank();
                        Thread xb = new Thread(b);
                        xb.start();
                        x.setVisible(false);

                        break;

                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException s)
    {

    }
}
}
```

and this is the code that im have a problem.

```
public void GateKeeper()
{
    try
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("DATABASE.txt"));
        int loop = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int gk=0;gk<loop;gk++)
        {
            String ps[] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            us = ps[0];
            pw = ps[1];
            if(acc1.getText().equals(us));
            {
                if(pin1.getText().equals(pw))
                {
                    xn = ps[2];
                    xage = ps[3];
                    xsex = ps[4];
                    xbal = ps[5];
                    xacc = ps[0];



                            Xn = new JLabel("NAME: "+xn);
                            Xacc = new JLabel("ACCOUNT NUMBER: "+xacc);
                            Xage = new JLabel("AGE: "+xage);
                            Xsex = new JLabel("SEX: "+xsex);
                            Xbal = new JLabel("BALANCE: "+xbal);

                        Bank b = new Bank();
                        Thread xb = new Thread(b);
                        xb.start();
                        x.setVisible(false);

                        break;

                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException s)
    {

    }
}
```

and this is the class that the GateKeeper is calling .

```
public class Bank extends Xavier1
{



public void reader()
{
    try
    {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("DATABASE.TXT");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException s)
    {

    }
}


public Bank()
{
    X = new JFrame("BANK");
    X.setVisible(true);
    X.setBounds(400,100,550,500);
    X.setLayout(null);
    x.setVisible(false);


    JPanel info = new JPanel();
    X.add(info);
    info.setVisible(true);
    info.setBounds(50,10,400,400);
    info.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));



    info.add(Xn);
    info.add(Xacc);
    info.add(Xage);
    info.add(Xsex);
    info.add(Xbal);






}
public static void main(String args[])
{


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent z1)
{
    Object z2 = z1.getSource();
}

}
```

and this is the errors i get :(

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
at Bank.<init>(Bank.java:43)
at Xavier1.GateKeeper(Xavier1.java:183)
at Xavier1.actionPerformed(Xavier1.java:117)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Something is `null` there. Debug your code :)

Comment: Where are you initializing `Xn`, `Xacc`, `Xage`, `Xsex` and `Xbal`, that you're adding in the `Bank` constructor?

Comment: Which lines causes the error?

Comment: Where is the instance of X? you're using it in your Bank() Constructor. The NullPointerException must be at your Bank() Constructor.

Comment: In Bank.java line 43 (inside the Bank constructor) there is some null dereference. I do not see anything suspicious, but look yourself at that line.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where the exception is happening, but do you have two variables, "X" and "x", in your Bank class where the variable with the lowercase x is not initialized correctly?

```
X.setLayout(null);
x.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you pass null to one of the call of java.awt.Container.add(Component comp)

```
public Bank() {
    ...

    X.add(info);
    ...
    info.add(Xn);
    info.add(Xacc);
    info.add(Xage);
    info.add(Xsex);
    info.add(Xbal);
}
```

check all values (info, Xn, Xacc, etc.) are not null

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in these lines. You never instanciate these variables: `x, Xn, Xacc, Xage, Xsex, Xbal`.

```
x.setVisible(false);

info.add(Xn);
info.add(Xacc);
info.add(Xage);
info.add(Xsex);
info.add(Xbal);
```

I would also suggest that you use proper naming to your objects. As it is now it is very hard to see what the difference between x and X is. It also makes it easier for you to avoid strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, that when the constructor of the Bank class is called,it implicitly calls the super class(Xavier1), which initializes all the global variable to null. Therefore you are getting this Exception at the Xn,Xacc,Xage,Xsex. I hope you can understand me.